# Problem Adding Custom actions in the Ribbon.DocLibListForm section

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, custom-action

Good day,

I am trying to add a custom action button for the "edit properties" form ribbon, but the button is still not being displayed. The solution is going to be deployed in a farm level and for a custom list (with id 10001 for this example)

```
<CustomAction Id="DocumentExchange"
            Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.EditForm"
            Title="element title"
            RegistrationType="List"
            RegistrationId="10001">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.DocLibListForm.Edit.Actions.Controls._children">
      <Button
        Id="ExchangeDocumentButton"
        Sequence="1"   
        Command="ExchangeDocument"
        LabelText="label text"
        Image32by32="/_layouts/images/myIcon.png"
        TemplateAlias="o2"
        />          
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="ExchangeDocument"
      CommandAction="javascript:alert('Not implemmented functionality call');"
      />
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

I wonder if the problem has to be that is not a sandbox level deployment solution or if some additional solution configuration is missing in the site.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated your example and the button shows up on the edit form on a custom document library with a RegistrationId of 10001. So nothing seems wrong.

The custom document library and the custom action are in one project and in one feature in my test environment and I scoped the feature to Site. 
How did you organize this?

One thing: you are missing the closing tag of CustomAction in the xml. Is this present in your solution?

Is there maybe other code present in your solution which can cause an exception or something?

Regards, Anita

Comment: Another thing: are you sure the feature is activated?

Comment: I too have the same problem. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Document libraries have RegistrationId of 101, can you try this?

Hope this helps, Anita

Comment: Hello Anita, thanks a lot for replying. The ID "10001" corresponds to a custom document library. The button is displayed if the location is set just to Location="CommandUI.Ribbon", but it has to be visible only in the edit item section. 
I was using the link below as reference, specifically "Add a Button to the Edit Form" but I couldn't make it work. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473643.aspx
I would really appreciate any guidance. Thanks again.